# How to organize and structure user albums of images in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, filesystems, directory-structure

One of my sites has a lot of users.  They currently each have one profile pic.  To keeps things fast and efficient, I've spread the profile images out based on their unique `UserID` so that no directory has more than 1,000 elements.

However, now I want to allow my users to upload more pics to their profile, but I have no idea how to organize and structure this when there's more than one image for each user.  I would obviously structure each user's album under their current unique folder, but how?

Do I use the Database to keep track of how many images each user has?  Do I ensure each file is named sequentially from 1 to however many that user has and display them always in that order (and if the user changes the order, I just rename them in the correct order)?  Or do I do it some other way?

The main difficulty I'm having is in knowing and keeping track of how many images each user has (especially if they delete one or two in the middle), what order they are in (which should be modifiable), and what naming convention to use, while keeping things fast, logical, and efficient.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a database table, other than confirming the file exists where-ever you place it, always use the data table to find and organize images.

User adds file:

1. Upload File
2. Create a hash of UserID and microtime
3. Write to disk using hash.ext
4. Confirm file exists.
5. Write to database, imageID (pk), userID, path/to/image.jpg, timestamp

User deletes file:

1. Confirm file exists on disk (look up where based on imageID passed)
2. Delete file using hash selected from query (don't let them pass a file name)
3. Delete row from database

Comment: I wanted to post a similar answer, but was frightened by the "while keeping things fast". Can you guarantee it is?

Comment: @jadkik94 without a definition for "fast", who can say.  Querying the database table to display the images should be "fast".